# Encoding problems with PDF

Tags: java, rest, character-encoding, pdfbox

I have a (quite simple) java Spring Boot/REST service that renders PDF from input and testing it with IntelliJ.

I use pdfbox as the tool to create such pdfs.

One feature is that the client can give annexes as `byte[]` in addition to the regular content it wants.

### Problem

When users tries the service, **the final document has blank pages only for the annexes part**.

### Investigation

- Tried with IntelliJ and HTTP REST Client and got the same issue
- **Saving the annexes into a separate files give a clear and correct document**
- **Saving the whole document (regular content + annexes) into a file is correct as well**.
- **Using postman, the document is fine**....

When I notice that with postman it's working great, I changed the IntelliJ default file encoding for the response file that is generated (from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1) and then successive documents are clear and correct...
Don't forget that this problem seems to only affect annexes. The regular content is always fine.

### Question

- I suppose this is an encoding problem in annexes content. am I correct ?
- Any way can i handle this on my side without impacting users service? Meaning to avoid some dev on their side.

### Other Information

I tried many bytes conversion without success, for instance:

```java
new String(annexe, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

But each time I got an exception:

```java
java.io.IOException: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid stored block lengths
```

The document is sent back as `byte[]` like this:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
pdfDocument.save(outputStream);
pdfDocument.close();
return outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Saving the document into a file is quite the same code, just a `FileOutputStream` is given instead.

Annexes are added to the document like this:

```java
for(byte[] content : annexes) {
    PDDocument annex = PDDocument.load(content);
    for (PDPage page : annex .getPages()) {
        pdfDocument.importPage(page);
    }
}
```

I also tried the PDFMergerUtility but got the same result (blank pages for annexes)

Comment: In what way is IntelliJ important to this problem?

Comment: You are right maybe my formulation is wrong. What I mean is that it does not work with it because of the default way it encode the file guessing my client has the same problem i guess... I'll edit.

Comment: if `annexe` is a PDF file then you should never put it into a `String` bacause PDF is a binary format. Besides that, I've not really understood the problem: "Saving the whole document (regular content + annexes) into a file is correct" but when you do it with the REST client it is bad? How about saving it on the server side into a file and then compare with a hex editor  with what you get on the client side?

Comment: Not sure about the problem either, it's part of my question. The response is ok but some client is able to save it into a correct pdf and others cannot. I'm guessing annexes are not encoded the same way as the rest. I already made a compare of files and they are differents. Problem is that when I check the raw response with intelliJ content lenght is the same. The save with a certain encoding seems to produce the problem for annexes. I would like a way  that for instance an UTF-8 encoding will 'always' works. Maybe I can do something with the annexes on my side.

Comment: It's a binary so it should be encoded in something for binary transfer, e.g. base64.

Comment: The annexes input is a `base 64 encoded string` that is naturally converted into a `byte[]` by Spring. Saving the `PDDocument object` into a file works but i guess it uses the default encoding of the os? For somes clients, the save of the response into a file make the annexes page to be blank. Maybe i'm missing smth but i don't understand what you mean.. Today the service return a `byte[]` as content and the mime type is set as `application/pdf`. Works fine excepts for annexes page. Not sure if my response match your remark tbh...

Comment: Saving PDDocument into a file (with PDDocument.save(file)) does not use any "encoding". (Btw, are you using the latest version? 2.0.16) One should investigate what the hex differences are. You might also to include minimal, but working code in your question.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version. What piece of code do you want to see? I can also include the controller code but so far all it does is returning the `byte[]`. For the rest, it's just taking style and data and creating a pdf file.  Only problem that remains is that with some clients the response is producing blanks pages for annexes.

Comment: Ideally, the smallest code that reproduces the effect and that people here can try on their own system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tilman Hausherr suggestion, I tried to encode the `byte[]` with `Base64.getEncoder().encode(...)` and this does the work!

The client has to deal with a Base64 encoded string now but it works at least.

Thank you!